# How to update user information properly, using spring boot and openAPI?

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, openapi, openapi-generator

I have UserController that signs up and updates information about user:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController implements UserApi {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final UserValidator userValidator;
    
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Token> signUpUser(@Valid User user) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.signUp(user));
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Void> updateUser(@Valid User user) {
        userService.update(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok();
    }

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(userValidator);
    }
}
```

`UserApi` interface is generated from openAPI.

A model `User` is also generated:
[User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaTSs.png)

`User` is validated by `UserValidator`

```
@Component
public class UserValidator extends AbstractValidator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return User.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        rejectIfBlank(errors, "username");
        rejectIfBlank(errors, "password");
        rejectIfBlank(errors, "name");

        rejectIfNull(errors,"phone");
        rejectIfBadPhone(errors, "phone");

        rejectIfNull(errors,"email");
        rejectIfBadEmail(errors,"email");
    }
}
```

`AbstractValidator` just implements  `org.springframework.validation.Validator` and adds some methods.

If validation fails, `ErrorHandlingControllerAdvice` does the job:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ErrorHandlingControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    ValidationErrorResponse onMethodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
    //create response
    }
}
```

So, to sign up new user client needs to send a user object with not blank password, but it's not necessary when updating. Thus, I need to validate user differently depending on function. I cannot use JSR-303 because of openAPI and I also couldn't find ways to do this using two different validators.

Does anybody know, how to do validation correctly here?

Comment: The validations for `Phone` and  `Email` are something complex where you have used regx  or some code to validate those. If not then you can just simply use @NotBlank @NotNull annotations from `spring-boot-starter-validation` to validate your model.

Comment: @KunalVarpe, I cannot use @NotBlank or @NotNull, because model User is auto-generated from openAPI, so I cannot annotate fields. But that's okay, the problem is that I need to validate user object in `signUpUser()` and `updateUser()` differently. When signing up I want to ensure that password is not blank, when updating - I don't.